# Advanced DataMapper search for Many to Many relation

Tags: datamapper, ruby-datamapper

Give the [Tag/Photo exemple](http://datamapper.org/docs/associations.html) on DataMapper documentation:

```
 class Photo
   include DataMapper::Resource

   property :id, Serial

   has n, :taggings
   has n, :tags, :through => :taggings
 end

 class Tag
   include DataMapper::Resource

   property :id, Serial

   has n, :taggings
   has n, :photos, :through => :taggings
 end

 class Tagging
   include DataMapper::Resource

   belongs_to :tag,   :key => true
   belongs_to :photo, :key => true
 end
```

I want to select all tags that has no photos
I know I can do

```
Tag.select { |tag| tag.photos.size < 1}
```

But I'd like more Datamapper syntax. Something like

```
Tag.all :photos.count.lt => 1  #not works
```

Is there a way to do this?
Does anyone knows a nice Datamapper documentation for advanced queries? [Documentation at the site](http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html) is very nice, but too basic.

Tkz

Answer (score 0):

`Tag.all(:photos => nil)` will get what you want in 2 SQL queries.
If you prefer one complex query, you have to write a custom SQL and execute it with `repository(:default).adapter.select('SELECT ...')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Tag.photos.all(:count.lt => 1)
```

Comment: This only worked for me if you have an attribute called count on photos.... But it is not the case..